# C# constructor for type parameterized abstract class

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class, type-parameter

So I found a lot of answer to the question if and why it is ok to have a constructor defined in an abstract class.

I am currently trying to make a parameterized constructor available in an abstract class which has a type parameter:

```
public abstract class Cell<T>
{
    int address;
    T value;

    protected Cell<T>(int address, T value)
    {

    }
}
```

But c# simply refuses it and Intellisense completely breaks down. 
So why is it possible to have a constructor in an abstract class but as soon as the abstract class gets a type parameter everything refuses it?

Comment: This is not specific to abstract classes. Use the same syntax for constructors of any generic class/struct, i.e. do not repeat the `<T>` list of generic arguments in the constructor name. You can still use `T` inside all parts of the generic type, including the instance constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `<T>` from the constructor declaration and then everything will work. For example, this compiles just fine:

```
public abstract class Cell<T>
{
    int address;
    T value;

    protected Cell(int address, T value)
    {

    }
}

public class CellInt : Cell<int>
{
    public CellInt(int address, int value): base(address, value) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor should look like this:

```
protected Cell(int address, T value)
{

}
```

You don't need to specify the type parameter in the constructor.

The point of a constructor in an abstract class is to force derived classes to call one of the abstract class' constructors from any constructor that the derived classes define.